# Using SystemMediaTransportControls w/o local media

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I am trying to use `SystemMediaTransportControls` on my Windows Phone to remote control my streaming music player device (I am not playing any media local to my device!). I am folowing the examples but have no success so far. The media controls do not appear on the screen.

Has anybody tried the same thing already? Is this possible at all, or does the media controls require a locally played music file to appear?

Answer (score 0):

The system media transport controls are only shown when the [MediaPlayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.playback.mediaplayer.aspx) has media opened and/or is playing media. You can't use it for any other purpose.